# Why QGIS never uses more than 4GB of RAM

Tags: qgis

I see QGIS never uses more than about 4GB of RAM. I'm aware of the 32/64 bit difference, and in order to exclude some issues with my PC I tried a rather big Windows Server 2019 instance on AWS with 64GB of memory.
I had a very big raster file and I made some operations on it, but again I never saw RAM usage go above 4GB, the CPU itself seemed stuck at only 25%.
Is there anything that someone should tweak to unblock all the system resources?

Comment: Why should an app use more RAM than it needs to?  Just because you access a 1TB raster doesn't mean that more than a couple of *megabytes* needs to be allocated to effectively use it. It's probably more worth the time looking for places where *less* RAM is needed.

Comment: Ok, but does that mean I already hit a plateau of performance? how can I make the program go faster?

Comment: Has Windows Server got spatial / geom support? How does QGIS work with that? Can you write your processing commands directly to the Windoze machine?

Comment: CPU usage at 25% can mean that all CPUs are not used. Multithreading may be better controlled with GDAL command line utilities. Low memory usage is usually not an issue because GDAL processes image data in chunks. You should define with more details what you are doing and what kind of source data you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broadly speaking QGIS is limited by the providers. These are the converters between the format of data you are working on and the code of the software. The code (roughly);  Qt and python. The providers (roughly); gdal, ogr, some of those two wrapped up in GRASS.

So QGIS is built to be a swiss army knife to do any small job out of the GUI. It accesses all manner of heavy duty tools in simplistic ways to help you finish a job from start to finish.

For heavy processing, you need to understand the specialist tools. For rasters, the goto for me used to be GRASS. Now I am considering the raster support in postgis, running on a postgresql server. All the commands to process the raster would be command line sql type stuff. GRASS has a sound GUI but the user must still be prepared to understand a lot of switches and novel commands.

You used to be able to access GRASS as a "plugin" to QGIS, or directly as it's standalone software. Either way, the manual will help https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/rasterintro.html

Comment: It was my understanding that saga and grass etc. were executed in the background and that qgis offered an easy way to write the input. Do you have any experience in running postgis inside the ubuntu subsystem for windows? or the real enhancement comes from a dedicate db server?

Comment: QGIS has DBManager which has a SQL window in which you can write commands direct to the postgresql/postgis db. The server hosting the db then takes the load of processing. It therefore avoids the "provider/connector".